# missing artifact javax .validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1 final

Tags: spring, maven, dependencies

I added dependency for `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-boot-starter-jdbc`and `mysql-connector-java`.

And I get problem: `"missing artifact javax .validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1 final.`"

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in you pom as `javax.validation` is part of it..and run `mvn clean install` once to reload all dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

see web dependency tree here..`javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final`

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.32:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.32:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.32:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.11.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
```

Answer (score 8):

Starting from version `2.3.0.RELEASE` Spring Boot Web and WebFlux starters no longer depend on the validation starter and `spring-boot-starter-validation` should be explicitely added to pom.xml.

[Spring Boot 2.3 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters)

Comment: Perfect! This is the answer I was looking for! Thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solve the issue :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

[Here the dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final)

Answer (score 0):

To add this we need to add like this.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
   <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).